# What clothing should I bring to Dubai during February?

Tags: clothing, dubai

I will be visiting Dubai for 4 days in February from now (never been) and I need to know what clothes I should plan on bringing with me.  Specifically I need proper clothes for dinner, attending events (cricket match, camel racing, dune safari, etc), and just touring around town.  The weather should be fairly mild at 80F and lower so I would consider anything a reasonable option. Also, is there anything else outside of clothing that I need to make sure I have while in Dubai?

I will also be spending some time at a resort in The Maldives but I'm pretty sure swimwear is most appropriate there :-)

Comment: Do you plan to visit their [ski resort](https://www.theplaymania.com/skidubai)?

Comment: Possibly.  Not high on our priority list since we live in a ski-laden area, Seattle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dubai is the heart of the Middle East, people from all over the world come to Dubai and in a place with this mixture of people you will not face a problem with clothes, simply because many of these tourists are coming from many places with different clothing cultures and many of them just wear whatever they wear at home! Anyway your profile says that you are from the US, just wear exactly what you wear in the US and you will be fine, such as jeans and shorts.

Regarding the weather, daytime it will be warm, night time it might be little cold sometimes so a sweater will help. Regarding dinner it depends what kind of restaurant (high class, normal, etc).

Regarding night clubs, many of them have a dress code, so avoid wearing blue jeans.

I also suggest that you buy an Arabian dress (in the UAE they call it Kandoura) and try it in daytime especially if it was hot, you will like it. It was designed to be worn in the hot areas and the way it was designed helps in cooling the body during hot days. You really should try it.

Comment: +1 for this. My first two days there I wore jeans in 40+C trying to be polite, until I realised every other tourist and many locals were just wearing shorts.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I'll look into getting a Kandoura, any tips or suggestions on which one to buy?

Comment: @BillJ They are almost the same, color is different and some design.. once you go to any Arabian dress shop you will see the differences yourself.. enjoy.